# I need to determine a set of users using X amount of modules

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

The exercise has two parts, A and B.

A is simple, it requires to check the modules that each user makes use of and return an object with the following format. This part is solved.

```
{
 'auth_module': {
    'authn.provider_1': ['./u1.json', './u2.json']
    'authn.provider_2': ['./u3.json', './u4.json', './u5.json']
  },
'content_module': {
    'authz.provider_1': ['./u1.json', './u3.json'],
    'authz.provider_2': ['./u2.json', './u4.json'],
    'authz.provider_3': ['./u5.json']
  }
}
```

Now, in part B I need help to solve this:

> "Determine a group of users (taken from part A) that together use all
> the available modules"

The example output is in this format:

```
['./u1.json', './u4.json', './u5.json']
```

I genuinely have no clue on how to solve this, so any kind of help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Using [`Object#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), iterate over the `auth_module` pairs while updating a list of target users

  - In each iteration, parse the provider id and get the list of content users for that provider if any
  - Using [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), iterate over the current auth users and update the target list with common ones between the two
- In case there were content-only providers only, we need to push the users to the list as well. Using [`Object#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), iterate over the `content_module` pairs

  - In each iteration, check if the current provider id is not in the `auth_module` to add its users
- Finally, return the list of unique users using [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
const _getUsers = modules => {
  const authIdPrefix = 'authn.', contentIdPrefix = 'authz.';
  const { 'auth_module': authModule, 'content_module': contentModule } = modules;
  
  const users = Object.entries(authModule)
    .reduce((list, [authProvider, authUsers]) => {
      const providerId = authProvider.substring(authIdPrefix.length);
      const contentUsers = contentModule[`${contentIdPrefix}${providerId}`] ?? [];
      authUsers.forEach(user => {
        if(contentUsers.includes(user)) {
          list.push(user);
        }
      });
      return list;
    }, []);

  Object.entries(contentModule)
    .forEach(([contentProvider, contentUsers]) => {
      const providerId = contentProvider.substring(contentIdPrefix.length);
      if(!authModule[`${authIdPrefix}${providerId}`]) {
        users.push(...contentUsers);
      }
    });

  return [...new Set(users)];
}

const modules = {
  'auth_module': {
    'authn.provider_1': ['./u1.json', './u2.json'],
    'authn.provider_2': ['./u3.json', './u4.json', './u5.json']
  },
  'content_module': {
    'authz.provider_1': ['./u1.json', './u3.json'],
    'authz.provider_2': ['./u2.json', './u4.json'],
    'authz.provider_3': ['./u5.json']
  }
};
console.log( _getUsers(modules) );
```

Comment: so this is the power of a true elden lord